# FF View Source | Script highlighted red

Tags: javascript

FF14 is highlighting my script tag red on a view->source

out of all my tags, just this on here:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

Is there  something it doesn't like ?

Thanks.

Comment: "FF is highlighting my script tag red" --- what does it look like?

Comment: Does the script actually work? I mean you could try changing the ' to "

Comment: @Thomas: anything wrong with single quote?

Comment: "wrong" no, but maybe FF is being stupid? Perhaps its red because it means script? I don't use FF personally.

Comment: why not use an HTML validator? It would have pointed out the problem very quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing your script within the HTML tag. Perhaps it doesn't like that it is out there on its own.

Answer (score 1):

SGML/HTML permit only one root element. In HTML, that should be `html`. You, however, have put the `script` element *after* the `html` element is closed.

It's not valid for an element to thus appear outside the root element. A script tag should occur inside the `head` or the `body`. (It shouldn't stop it from working, because browsers are very lenient, but it's not valid.)